# How to Cycle Through Links (sequentially) Each Page Load

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to a cycle through 5 links and want to cycle through them on each page load (i.e. first visitor page load shows link 1, second visitor page load shows link 2, etc. then back to link 1 after link 5 shows)

I found this code below which does cycle through the links randomly, but I'm trying to get them to load in order. Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<li id="RotateLink"></li>

<script language="javascript">
var links = new Array("link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5");
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*5)
document.getElementById("RotateLink").innerHTML = links[randomnumber];
</script>
```

(also, some tips on changing "link1" to an actual link would be helpful too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you lose your JS context on page load, you could make use of the browser's inbuilt `localStorage` api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).

```
<li id="RotateLink"></li>

<script language="javascript">
  var links = new Array("link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5");
  var numberFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("cycle-link-number") || "0"; // zero if getItem returns null
  var number = parseInt(numberFromStorage); //cast to number since storage saves strings
  number = number >= links.length ? 0 : number; // reset if reached max
  localStorage.setItem("cycle-link-number", number + 1); //set item for next iteration
  document.getElementById("RotateLink").innerHTML = links[number];
</script>
```

To create your link you could do something like this:

```
// instead of
// document.getElementById("RotateLink").innerHTML = links[number];
// do
var link = document.createElement("a"); // creates anchor element
link.href = 'someUrl'; // sets the url, e.g link.href = 'http://www.google.de';
link.innerHTML = 'linktext'; // set the link text
document.getElementById("RotateLink").appendChild(link); // appends the link to the element with the id "RotateLink"
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I just tried the code and it didn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I need to add something else based on the local storage link you sent.

Comment: Should work. Can you share your Implementation or any error?

Comment: I just realized that i had a typo. Was getting links[randomnumber]. Updated it. And it should work now

Comment: I now just need to replace the "link1" with an actual link, such as `<a href="http://mylink.com">Link 1</a>` Do you have a quick tip for a non-java guy on how to easily do that? Once I have that, I'll be set. Thanks again!

Comment: I´m glad you got it working. My second snippet explains how to create a link via script.

Comment: I see that, but I'm not sure how to implement it for my links. Any explanation on how I could add that for my 5 links would be helpful, thanks again.

Comment: OK, thanks Stefan, I apologize for my js unfamiliarity. Your updated code is much clearer, however, still now sure how I include five links with your code above. Would I just do the link.href for 5 different links?

Answer (score 0):

As you need to know the link that was previously loaded after page reload, You need to store that information somewhere so that you can use it on the next reload. We have browser local storage to do that. You can store the index of the link that was previously loaded and increment the link based on that. More details about HTML5 Web Storage here [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```
<li id="RotateLink"></li>

<script language="javascript">

var links = new Array("link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5");

var currentIndex=localStorage.currentIndex;
if(currentIndex){
   if(currentIndex < links.length-1)
     currentIndex = parseInt(currentIndex)+1;
   else
     currentIndex = 0;
 } else {
     currentIndex = 0;
     localStorage.setItem('currentIndex', currentIndex);
 }
localStorage.currentIndex = currentIndex;
document.getElementById("RotateLink").innerHTML = links[currentIndex];

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks suzo, I just tried the code and it didn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I need to add something else based on the local storage link you sent. Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I made a fiddle for you. Check and let me know if this is what you are expecting :  https://jsfiddle.net/suzo/yzycajpu/